# jquery поочерёдность $.Deferred()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой тестовый пример:

```
var dfd_1 = $.Deferred(),
    dfd_2 = $.Deferred(),
    dfd_3 = $.Deferred();

function test(content, waitTime, dfd) {
    console.log(content + ' begin');
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(content + ' end');
        dfd.resolve();
    }, waitTime);
    return dfd.promise();
}

$.when(test('first', 2000, dfd_1), test('second', 4000, dfd_2), test('third', 6000, dfd_3))
.then(function() {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

Результат выполнения из консоли:

```
first begin 
second begin
third begin

first end
second end
third end

all done
```

А нужно во так:

```
first begin
first end

second begin
second end

third begin
third end

all done
```

Как сделать, что бы функции выполнялись поочередно с применением $.Deferred?
Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: еще один.. Зачем вам Deffered? Запускайте следующую функцию из конца предыдущей и не ломайте себе мозг.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В jQuery странные промисы(не соответствуют стандарту Promises/A+), поэтому лучше использовать .pipe, вместо then

```
test('first', 2000, dfd_1).pipe(function () {
    return test('second', 4000, dfd_2);
}).pipe(function () {
    return test('third', 6000, dfd_3);
}).pipe(function() {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не совсем корректно использовали промайсы. Подписывались не на те события.

```
        test('first', 2000, dfd_1)
        .done(function () {
            test('second', 4000, dfd_2)
            .done(function () {
                test('third', 6000, dfd_3)
                .done(function () {
                    console.log('all done');
                })
            })
        });
```